# WebView.CapturePreviewToStreamAsync() fails, but only on HoloLens with Unity3D

Tags: c#, xaml, unity-game-engine, webview, hololens

Currently, we're trying to combine the use of Unity3D holograms and HTML rendering in one app. The idea works as follows:

1) start a XAML app whose main window contains a WebView component (using the XAML app template)
2) Switch to Holographic (DirectX) mode (essentially copy over the code from the Holographic app template)
3) The WebView still runs in the background
4) We can call the `WebView.Navigate()` method
5) Render the contents of the WebView via the `CapturePreviewToStreamAsync()` API to a bitmap
6) Convert the bitmap to a texture and display it on the DirectX side- thus having HTML rendering with holograms

Our experiments so far work in:
1) C++/CX
2) C#

However, we have problems if we try to do the same thing with Unity3D. Here is what we do:
1) We create a Unity3D project with mixed reality support
2) We export the Unity project with "UWP Build type" set to "XAML" (instead of D3D).
That app builds within MSVS 2017 and starts as a XAML app which automatically switches to holographic space, showing correctly the scenes as defined in Unity.
3) We further edit the main XAML page to contain a WebView element (pointing to a webpage).

Now if we call the `CapturePreviewToStreamAsync()` API of the WebView component, a
System.Exception is thrown with message:
Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

The error is 100% reproducible and occurs if we use both the Hololens glasses and the emulator.

Any suggestions what might be the cause of the behavior? Seems that Unity creates the main window of the XAML part of the app in a different way, but we don't have access to that since the window creation happens mainly within the re-compiled Unity modules.

Thanks!
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although we couldn't find the reason for the exception, we found a workaround, by following the instructions in this blog entry by Jonathan Antoine :

[launch a 3D (Holograms) app from a 2D #XAML app and going back to it](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2016/06/29/hololens-launch-a-3d-holograms-app-from-a-2d-xaml-app-and-going-back-to-it-uwp/)

The way to make things work was to:
1. Create a new XAML page for the Unity3D generated app from above (let's name it WebViewPage, which contains our WebView component)
2. Modify the Unity generated XAML app to navigate to WebViewPage on startup instead of to the MainPage
3. When needed to switch to holographic space, just navigate to the MainPage the usual way:

```
    var frame = new Frame();
    Window.Current.Content = frame;
    frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```

4.  You might also need to move the `appCallbacks` object from the generated app from the `App` class to the `MainPage` class

That solved the problem. Now the `CapturePreviewToStreamAsync()` call works and returns the data.

NOTE: We noticed that the app leaves the HoloLens emulator (10.0.14393.1358) in some state which doesn't allow the app to be launched a second time without restarting the emulator. But that problem doesn't show up with on a real device

Hope that helps someone
Martin

Comment: Hi! I am currently trying to figure this out. Did you get it working in 3D space? And were you able to update the page async? Or was it just one state you were able to display? Also, in DirectX, how were you able to transfer the bitmap to a texture? Having major trouble with this, slowly going mad, any help would be amazing.

Comment: Hi,

We did manage to make it work, but it was as a part of a project in my previous work, so unfortunately I won't be able to provide any additional source code.

We experimented and we were able to load a HTML page into the webview after the holographic mode has been activated, extract it, and then display it. 
More specifically, are you asking about converting of bitmap data into DirectX textures or  about the use of both DirectX and XAML in the same app?
I might still be able to provide some guidelines

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for getting back to me. I have been struggeling with this for days now and am now again at the point where I would like to use Unity for this instead of directX. My specific questions now would be: I have a seperate view with the webview, but I am still getting the catastrophic failure. I can't figure out how to move the appcallbacks to my new view. Was this a critical part in getting the error to go away?

Comment: Actually think I've got it. Turns out I was calling my MainPage wrong, I was using your snippet as the total page call. But using the `CoreApplication.CreateNewView();` etc from the blog you mentioned was the way to do it. I think the error has to do with the different Dispatchers, and by explicitly creating a new view, you get a new dispatcher for the Unity stuff, and one for the XAML UI stuff. Thanks so much for all the help!