# Play youtube video as a hololgram

Tags: youtube, hololens

Is there any way to open a window and playing a youtube video inside my hololens app?

I did search about opening youtube video page, but it will open outside of my, i want player to be inside of my app.

Comment: What you need is an Chromium embedded Framework like CefGlue to load the web. At present, there seems to be no perfect plugin that can be imported directly.

In addition, I also find  this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445940/webview-capturepreviewtostreamasync-fails-but-only-on-hololens-with-unity3d, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HoloLens 1, the suggestions provided by Hernando in the comments are good.

I wanted to also share that it is possible to do this on HoloLens 2 and Windows Mixed Reality simply by launching a URI. This will launch a flat application window directly in your unity app. For example, have a look at ["the Launch External Apps pull request"](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/pull/5047#issuecomment-506881653) which shows the behavior in the HandInteractionExamples scene (available in MRTK RC2 release, or latest mrtk_development branch).

The code to launch an external URI within your app is as follows:

```
#if WINDOWS_UWP
            UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(async () =>
            {
                bool result = await global::Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("https://youtu.be/SB-qEYVdvXA"));
            }, false);
#else
            Application.OpenURL("https://youtu.be/SB-qEYVdvXA");
#endif
```

This code was taken from [LaunchUri.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/mrtk_development/Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Examples/Demos/HandTracking/Script/LaunchUri.cs), modified to just launch a YouTube video.