# button that open some browser link in unity for HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I created a button that opens a weblink in Unity for HoloLens, but the button is not showing up on screen.

The project:
[image: You can see the project here.]

Answer (score 0):

In Unity every UI Element must be a child of a canvas. You can just create a canvas make the button a child of the canvas.

You can read [the docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UICanvas.html) to get a better understanding of canvases and the Unity UI system.

Answer (score 0):

You can double-click the GameObject from the Hierarchy window to locate it in the Scene. Besides, if you have any question about how to launch a URI, please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57529694/11502506